# Azure Devops pipelines: Condition inside loop not working?

Tags: azure-devops

In trying to run a script on a loop only if a variable is true but the script never runs :(
It works if i set it as "condition:" to the script but i would like for the task to not even be printed if not to run, therefore would like to use the ${{if...}}
(tried with boolean and string)

```
parameters:
  charts: []
  outputChartsDebugInfo: false

steps:
- ${{ each chart in parameters.charts }}:
  - script: | 
            echo "TEST ${{parameters.outputChartsDebugInfo}}" #this outputs true
            echo "Deployment values:"
            echo "chart name - ${{chart.Name}}"
            #...               
    displayName: Deploy ${{chart.Name}}

  - ${{ if eq(parameters.outputChartsDebugInfo, true) }}:
    - script: |
              echo "DEBUG:"
              #...         
      displayName: Show ${{chart.Name}} debug info
```

Should this be working?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to change is how you set your parameters. Then, you should loop over an object that contains some values. Your `charts` object is empty in your code.

```
parameters:
  - name: charts
    type: object
    default: [one,two]
  - name: outputChartsDebugInfo
    default: false


steps:
- ${{ each chart in parameters.charts }}:
  - script: | 
            echo "TEST ${{parameters.outputChartsDebugInfo}}" #this outputs true
            echo "Deployment values:"
            echo "chart name - ${{chart}}"
    displayName: Deploy ${{chart}}

  - ${{ if eq(parameters.outputChartsDebugInfo, true ) }}:
    - script: |
              echo "DEBUG:"
      displayName: Show ${{chart }} debug info
```

Comment: both charts value and outputChartsDebugInfo value are passed in the calling script and runs as expected (commented #this outputs true - it really does)

Comment: So after a few tests found the issue, the if inside the loop works as expected,seems that is "refusing to read the value form variable", if i pass as
` steps:
  - template: charts-pipeline-template.yml
     parameters:
      outputChartsDebugInfo: 'True'
       charts: 
        - Name: xxx         
        - Name: yyy
`
it works, if i pass 
` steps:
  - template: charts-pipeline-template.yml
     parameters:
      outputChartsDebugInfo: $(outputDebug)
       charts: 
        - Name: xxx
        - Name: yyy
`
it evaluates as False all times, variable not expanding?...

Answer (score 0):

Just it case its handy for anyone, the if inside the loop works fine, the parameters outputChartsDebugInfo was being read from a variable, but the syntax used $(var), expands only at runtime before a task executes, and the necessary is that it expands at compile time, so the fix in this case was change the syntax on the variable in the calling script:

```
steps:
- template: charts-pipeline-template.yml
  parameters:
      outputChartsDebugInfo: ${{variables.outputChartsDebugInfo}}

      charts: 
        - Name: xxx
        - Name: yyy
```

instead of

```
steps:
- template: charts-pipeline-template.yml
  parameters:
      outputChartsDebugInfo: $(outputChartsDebugInfo)

      charts: 
        - Name: xxx
        - Name: yyy
```